# PHP and MySQL Query Filtering

Tags: php, mysql

I work for a small biotech company and we store a lot of our data in Google Docs spreadsheets. This is fine for a lot of things, but for some types of information (cell lines we have in stock and which freezer vials and boxes they are located in, for example) it really isn't the greatest format. I've taught myself a bit of MySQL and PHP and have managed to create a basic database storing the relevant information and a simple web interface capable of displaying it. Of course to be useful it needs some type of filtering/search functionality, and this is where I'm getting a bit confused.

For any given search I'm aware of how to write a MySQL query for it, and how to get it from the field/predicate/value tuples that will comprise the filter the user will give, but I'm not too sure at exactly what level the filtering should be done. Right now I basically have a view in the database set up for each "table" that will be presented to the user (a view is necessary because the information presented to the user comes from several database tables and one or more joins are performed). I then have a PHP object that will create the basic query given the database and view name, append a WHILE clause and all the filtering stuff if necessary (e.g. appending "WHERE box_number = ?" to the prepared statement, and storing the number 211 in an array to be passed when I call the execute function), then run the query and display the results as an HTML table. I plan on extending the object to build specific functionality into different tables, such as having the `box number` field be a hyperlink that will take you to a page showing a freezer box's contents when you click it.

I've only been learning about PHP and databases for a past couple of weeks, though, so I'm not sure if this is the best way to accomplish this. My roommate, who does this sort of stuff at Cisco, has suggested that using a stored procedure would be a better choice. I've been looking into this but I'm not sure it's possible to pass a stored proc an arbitrary number of parameters like I would need to to implement filtering. I've also seen some sources say it's better to just get the whole table/view and do the filtering in PHP.

So, is there a "standard" or "best" way to accomplish this? The tables aren't going to be very big for this project, several hundred entries at the most probably. So performance isn't really an issue. Mostly I just need a method where everything is fairly flexible and can be easily updated if the database structure changes (likely will be adding more column/fields to most of the tables in the future). I can probably get any of these methods to work but I'd like to know which one might be best for my situation so I don't end up needing to rework everything later.

Comment: My instinct is that until the data becomes too large to manage, the filtering should be done, as much as possible, client-side. Consider a website like kiva. You can filter for all kinds of things there apparently (I think) without making any asynchronous calls back to the database. The data's already in the DOM.

Comment: Sounds like you need a database hooked up to a reporting solution. I'm not sure I would recommend writing it yourself, since it _must_ already exist - something like "MS Access for the web". Have a look here for ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387144/php-report-generator

Comment: I don't see that stored procedures are _necessarily_ a better choice, though they can return a recordset just in the same way as a view. The critical thing is (a) what queries do you have, (b) what parameters do they require, and what types/validations do they have, and what labels should they have (c) how should each query be rendered when it is run, and (d) who can run which queries. That, essentially, is what reporting software will do for you.